# Как собрать из 64 битной программы 32 rpm?

Tags: c++, linux

Кто знает, как собрать из 64 битной программы 32 rpm? Пробую `rpmbuild -bb --target i686`, в g++ передается `RPM_OPT_FLAGS=-O2 -g -march=i686`, на что он говорит:

> error: заданный процессор не поддерживает набор команд x86-64.

Для нормальной сборки под 32 бита нужно передать еще и -m32. Вопрос, куда приткнуть -m32, чтобы не нарушала логику или как сделать, чтобы она сама добавлялась?

Comment: Я так понял, что имеются 64-битные бинарники, которые нужно собрать в  rpm-пакет, подписанный как 32-битный? Если так, то это плохая идея. Если же надо собрать 32-битник на 64-битной системе, то наверняка есть скрипт, на основе которого rpmbuild компилирует и собирает пакет. Туда и смотри. Там нужно где-то указать флаг -m32

Comment: Не так, есть исходный код программы, которую нужно собрать в rpm. Для 64 бит собралось отлично, а для 32 пока собираться не хочет. В справке пишут, что вроде достаточно опции --target i686, но ее не хватает. Попробую покопаться еще, может найду, где добавляется -m32, ведь этот флаг по любому должен передаваться в g++ для сборки под 32 бита.